# Datepicker in a slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

[Slider date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wczbu.png)

Can anyone please suggest a plugin through which I can achieve a calendar in a slider as shown in the image attached.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the following Library

[Bootstrap DatePaginator](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-datepaginator)

And also just go [here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-date-time-picker/)

Comment: Thank You Ramkee !!

Comment: I hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html#dateSliderQuickStart

And customize it.