# How to implement double range date Slider in react

Tags: reactjs, date, slider, rangeslider

I am tryin to implement date range slider which pick two date from slider in react , I am using material UI Library but there is no such clear explanation to customize it according to requirement.
[I want to use this type of slider which show in image and slider return me two value which is month and year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xvgs.png)

please let me update if have any idea regarding that, its very helpful to me.

thank you.

I am tryin to implement date range slider which pick two date from slider in react , I am using material UI Library but there is no such clear explanation to customize it according to requirement.

Comment: Have you referred to this previous [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544354/datepicker-in-a-slider)